# How to reduce the coordinates decimal in a local kml file using pykml?

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, kml, findall, pykml

I have a kml file that has cell with more than 1 million character. I want to reduce the number of decimal from 12 to 3. I imported lxml and pykml.

```
import pykml
from pykml.helpers import set_max_decimal_places
file1=open('\United States divisions. Level 2.kml')
from os import path
#set_max_decimal_places(file1, max_decimals={'longitude':3,'latitude':3,})
```

and I got this error:

```
     39         index_no = 0 # longitude is in the first position
     40         # modify <longitude>
---> 41         for el in doc.findall(".//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}longitude"):
     42             new_val = round(float(el.text), max_decimals[data_type])
     43             el.getparent().longitude = K.longitude(new_val)
```

AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'findall'

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are loading the kml as just a file and it needs to be parsed first. From: http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/tutorial.html

```
In [29]: from pykml import parser

...

In [40]: kml_file = path.join( \
   ....:      '../src/pykml/test', \
   ....:      'testfiles/google_kml_developers_guide', \
   ....:      'complete_tour_example.kml')

In [44]: with open(kml_file) as f:
   ....:      doc = parser.parse(f)
```

Then you can call:

```
   ....:      set_max_decimal_places(doc, max_decimals={'longitude':3,'latitude':3,})
```

**Update:**

Using your code above I think this should work too: ([from here](http://code.google.com/p/pykml/source/browse/src/pykml/test/test_helpers.py?r=e298901312f320da7ca1104aee9a8e193e8f0d6d))

```
file1=open('\United States divisions. Level 2.kml')
doc = fromstring(file1.read(), schema=Schema("ogckml22.xsd"))
set_max_decimal_places(doc, max_decimals=3)
```

**Update: 2**

Just pulling in the final code you used from your comment:

```
from lxml import etree 
from pykml.helpers import set_max_decimal_places 
from pykml import parser 

with open('\United States divisions. Level 2.kml') as f: 
    doc=parser.parse(f) 
    set_max_decimal_places(doc, max_decimals={'longitude':3,'latitude':3,}) 

print etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True) 
outfile = file(file.rstrip('.py')+'.kml','w') 
outfile.write(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: So - In the first situation I expect you just need to write the file back to disk? In the second I expect you have an attribute set that is not valid KML - try validating your document. If that is the case, just use the first method as you should not *need* to have a valid KML to make these updates or use it.

Comment: My comment before your last one was addressing this comment before you deleted / re-added it.

Comment: I suggest you start with the example in the linked documentation just using a string you set in the script. Once that is working try to load an excerpt of your file (a few records in a new test file from your huge document) and make sure that is working as expected. Then move on to processing the entire thing.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I'm trying to implement your point. I'm using nsmap, but still no success.

Comment: Finally it worked.  from lxml import etree 
from pykml.helpers import set_max_decimal_places
from pykml import parser
with open('C:\Users\Mehrnoosh Oghbaie\Desktop\Python\United States divisions. Level 2.kml') as f:
    doc=parser.parse(f)   
set_max_decimal_places(doc, max_decimals={'longitude':3,'latitude':3,})
print etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
outfile = file(__file__.rstrip('.py')+'.kml','w')
outfile.write(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True))